# two popup window is here.. i Close one popup, at the time other popup window doing one action?

Tags: jquery, html

Two popup window is here.i Close one popup,at the time other popup window doing one action? And both popup are different page

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand what you meant. You want one page do something when the other is closed? I'm almost sure you can't really do that.

Comment: Please elaborate on your question, sample code would be great too for quick help...

Comment: 2 html pages is here. first page one button click time one popup is open(another html page). there one button is here.. that button clicking time another popup(another html page) open.. I close the last popup . so the previous popup is showed now. here one trigger action required.

Answer (score 0):

function popup2_afterClose()
    {

```
    jQuery("#list").trigger("reloadGrid");

}
```

popup2(popup-id)
list- popup1 id